# Circular graph that plots weekdays and events?

Tags: time, graph, design-patterns, analysis

I'm trying to find/create a graph that allows me to plot the various day of the week as circles within circles.  So the innermost ring would be Sunday, the next outer ring would be Monday, etc.  And in a clockwise fashion, it would be the 24 hours of the day.  The goal is to see recurring patterns over the course of a day's time (the clockwise portion) as well as recurring activities (the circles part).

The goal being to analyze data so that I could say something like "every Monday at 9AM our power output spikes; maybe we should check into that anomaly and see why it happens".

It doesn't necessarily have to be a circular graph like I described, I just believe that would be the best way to visualize what I'm looking for, which is the ability to find patterns over the course of time.

I haven't really found any good graphs that meet this need.  But I'm not really sure what this type of graph would be called, either.  If anyone has any thoughts they'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Neat idea! You may also try turning it into a smooth spiral to really reinforce the connected-ness of the end of one day to the start of the next. I'd love to see this!

Comment: Interesting thought.  Once I hopefully get this implemented I'll drop back and give a visual of what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "radar chart" would probably meet your needs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart

Basically the angle is the hour, and the radius is whatever magnitude you're plotting. I've used these to plot cyclical data in the past with some success.

examples: http://images.google.com/search?q=radar+chart&hl=en&safe=off&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch

[image]

Comment: I think this will probably work but I'll need to do some tailoring to it.  It meets the same general principle that I'm looking for.  Thanks!